# Unique count with 2 parameters

Tags: excel, countif

I have a Google Excel sheet with 2 columns:

```
name paid

john y

john n

john n

pat n

peter n

greg n

ricardo n

barack y
```

I just need to count people who didn't paid.
In the case, **the result is 4** (because John).

I tried something like :

```
=COUNTIF(B:B;"n")
```

But it returns "6" and I don't know how to do with the second condition (if John paid also at the end).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula solution based on provided sample data, adjust ranges to suit your actual data:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A9<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A9,A2:A9&""))-COUNTIF(B2:B9,"y")
```

It gets the number of unique names from column A, and then subtracts the number of y's from column B.  This solution assumes there can only be one "y" per unique name, as is the case in your provided sample data.

So because there are a total of 6 unique names, and only 2 y's, the formula returns the expected answer of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Select all text, go to Insert => Pivot Table
In PivotTable field list, Drag 'Name' field to Row Labels. Also drag Paid to Column Labels as well as Values. You will now get the table with all measures you need, including sum of who paid, not paid, and counts

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not excactly what I need. I need to count the number of unique "n" and take into account if the person paid or not. In the case, the result needs to be 4.

Comment: Jose, is it that if there is one Y against a person after multiple Ns, he can be treated as paid? If so, you can sort the paid column from Z-A so that all Ys will come first followed by N. Now, you can remove duplicates of Name column (from Data Tab) and that will give you the one status per person, with status. Now, count or pivot will give you 4 for Ns.